# Rails 3.1.1 getting broken image on image assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm missing something with the asset pipeline functionality.  Things work fine in development and I move to run in production environment and all hell breaks loose!

So I have an image in app/assets/images named "logo.png"

1. I precompile (`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`) and I can verify that in public/assets there now exists both a **logo.png** and **logo-5fa60e416f495e562c56a5087fe696dc.png**
2. I then run in production `rails s thin -e production`
3. But I get a broken image

   GET http://localhost:3000/assets/logo-5fa60e416f495e562c56a5087fe696dc.png 404 (Not Found)

What is going on?

I also notice that when I switch to production I also starting getting javascript errors like "JQuery is not found" for jquery tools EVEN THOUGH no problems in development AND I specify in my application.js that jquery should be loaded first before any other javascript files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple (finding it was not).

Simply update your config/production.rb to reflect the following:

```
 config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Though this is set to false by default, only when you set it to true will you be able to properly run your rails 3.1.x application locally (via webbrick or in my case thin) in the production environment.  You'll probably want to set it back to false before you deploy to your actual production server.